# Why does error appear when I output like the following example?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Why does error appear when I output like the following example?
*In my class CTimeSpan, I create like the following example:
It's error cout<<tm1++;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CTimeSpan {
private:
    unsigned int day; //day
    unsigned int hour;
    unsigned int minute;
    unsigned int second;

public:
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const CTimeSpan& tm)
    {
        os << tm.day << "d"
           << " " << tm.hour << "h"
           << " " << tm.minute << "p"
           << " " << tm.second << "s";
        return os;
    }
    CTimeSpan CTimeSpan::operator++(int s) {
            CTimeSpan temp = *this;
            ++* this;
            return temp;
     }
};
int main()
{
    CTimeSpan tm1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    cout << tm1++; 
}
```

*thank you very much. Help me.

Comment: Your `<<` overload must take a `const CTimeSpan &` parameter, and not a `CTimeSpan &`. You also overloaded the `++` prefix operator instead of the postfix one. Your `++` overload should take a stub `int` parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, my code is incorrect , I have already edited, but my problem hasn't been solved yet. I want to cout<<i++, Would you mind solving it for me??

Comment: See "Unary arithmetic operators" in the linked question for an explanation of how to correctly implement the postfix `++` operator.